# Scheduled tasks is runnings two times in tomcat production

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have onde app spring-boot v2 with one class Scheduled, in developer enviroment my method `run` in class Scheduled run one times.
But i build for production (using `mvn clean package`) and publishing in tomcat 8
my task is executing two times

This is my class @Scheduled

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerEmailService {

    @Autowired
    private SenderEmailService senderEmailService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerEmailService.class);

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void run() {

        LOG.info("Status do Servico: " + taskService.isEnabled());
        if(taskService.isEnabled()) {       
            LOG.info("Executando... {}", LocalDateTime.now());
            senderEmailService.enviarEmail();
        }else {
            LOG.info("Falsa execução do servico... {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        }

    }


}
```

In production this is log

```
O servico foi parado
 Status do Servico: false
Falsa execução do servico... 2018-08-21T15:26:59.663
Status do Servico: true
Executando... 2018-08-21T15:27:01.183
Status do Servico: false
Falsa execução do servico... 2018-08-21T15:27:09.664
Status do Servico: true
Executando... 2018-08-21T15:27:11.368
```

See in log that her run one times for false and other for true.
Obs: I define that variable `taskService.isRunning` for `false`
but in exists other task in executing of value default `true`

**Edit**
I print in log the hash code class and this is a result:

```
2018-08-22 07:49:45.996  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Status do Servico: true
2018-08-22 07:49:45.996  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : HashCode Classe: 19875385
2018-08-22 07:49:45.996  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Executando... 2018-08-22T07:49:45.996
2018-08-22 07:49:50.730  INFO 8168 --- [pool-20-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Status do Servico: true
2018-08-22 07:49:50.730  INFO 8168 --- [pool-20-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : HashCode Classe: 11898713
2018-08-22 07:49:50.731  INFO 8168 --- [pool-20-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Executando... 2018-08-22T07:49:50.731
2018-08-22 07:49:56.121  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Status do Servico: true
2018-08-22 07:49:56.121  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : HashCode Classe: 19875385
2018-08-22 07:49:56.121  INFO 8168 --- [pool-19-thread-1] c.c.s.services.SchedulerEmailService     : Executando... 2018-08-22T07:49:56.121
```

Exists two diferent class in execution.
What resolve this ?

Comment: Could you extend the `LOG.info` to also output `this` or the `hashCode` of the instance? I'd like to see if there are more than one instances of the class.

Comment: sure, i make, will post result here

Comment: `Status do Servico: false 21694996
Status do Servico: true 521900`

the number after false or true is a hashcode of class

Comment: Whats is say ? class instance is duplicated ?

Answer (score 0):

From the hashCode in the log you can see that the `SchedulerEmailService` gets instantiated twice by Spring.
I'm not 100% sure about the reason but the `@EnableScheduling` annotation is not meant to be used on a bean class but on a `@Configuration` class

> Enables Spring's scheduled task execution capability, similar to functionality found in Spring's  XML namespace. To be used on @Configuration classes as follows:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html

I would suggest removing the `@EnableScheduling` annotation from `SchedulerEmailService` and adding a config like with a `ComponentScan` including the package of `SchedulerEmailService`.

```
@Service
public class SchedulerEmailService {

    // ...

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages="your.package")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did this changes like suggestion, but i can see class executing two times yet